# MySQL - Query not running in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that I'm using in a PHP function. Something breaks before it gets through the query, but it doesn't "echo" to the screen. (the calls above the query do show up). I'm kinda a newbie though, does anyway notice anything wrong here? Thanks!

```
function updateEmployee (Employee $emp){
    echo $emp->getStreetAddress();
    echo $emp->getCity();
    echo $emp->getState();
    echo $emp->getZip();
    echo $emp->getUsername();
    echo $emp->getPassword();
    echo $emp->getSsn();
    echo $emp->getPersonId();

    $query = "UPDATE Employees E JOIN Persons P ON E.personId = P.personId SET firstName=".$emp->getFirstName().
                ", lastName=".$emp->getLastName().
                ", phoneNum=".$emp->getPhoneNum().
                ", streetAddress".$emp->getStreetAddress().
                ", city=".$emp->getCity().
                ", state=".$emp->getState().
                ", zip=".$emp->getZip().
                ", username=".$emp->getUsername().
                ", password=".$emp->getPassword().
                ", ssn=".$emp->getSsn().
                " WHERE P.personId=".$emp.getPersonId().";";

    echo $query;

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }               
}
```

Comment: wrap single quotes around the new values

Comment: It's seems that you are not filtering nor sanitizing your code, and thats why input form values maybe breaking your code.

Comment: its for a small databases project due tomorrow, I haven't been very diligent

Comment: simplify the querry start with a single update

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty new to PHP myself, but I do notice that the WHERE line has `$emp.getSomething()` while the other lines have `$emp->getSomething()`. Notice the . instead of the `->`

Also, you can try adding this to the top of the page while debugging:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your SQL statement safer to execute, use single quoted strings in every field.

For example:

```
$query = "UPDATE Employees E JOIN Persons P ON E.personId = P.personId SET firstName='".$emp->getFirstName()."', lastName='".$emp->getLastName()."' 
WHERE P.personId='".$emp.getPersonId()."' ";
```